# how to make list by order of appearance and drop overlapping?

Tags: python, list

I have list below.

```
a = [4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1]
```

I want to drop overlapping, but preserve the order of appearance. So I want to get list like

```
b = [4, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

I don't drop all overlapping (want to drop if next or previous value is the same as previous or next value).

How can I write the code to get that list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
[k for k, _ in groupby(a)]
```

**Example**:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1]

print([k for k, _ in groupby(a)])
# [4, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```